# Cannot load backend 'Qt5Agg' or it doesn't show any plot

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to use 'Qt5Agg' matplotlib backend in Jupyter , but when I run `%matplotlib qt`, i get the following error:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-f6a92ad1c7f8> in <module>
----> 1 get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'qt')
      2 import numpy as np
      3 from scipy.integrate import odeint
      4 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      5 from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py in run_line_magic(self, magic_name, line, _stack_depth)
   2312                 kwargs['local_ns'] = sys._getframe(stack_depth).f_locals
   2313             with self.builtin_trap:
-> 2314                 result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
   2315             return result
   2316 

</home/cs/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/decorator.py:decorator-gen-108> in matplotlib(self, line)

~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/magic.py in <lambda>(f, *a, **k)
    185     # but it's overkill for just that one bit of state.
    186     def magic_deco(arg):
--> 187         call = lambda f, *a, **k: f(*a, **k)
    188 
    189         if callable(arg):

~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/magics/pylab.py in matplotlib(self, line)
     97             print("Available matplotlib backends: %s" % backends_list)
     98         else:
---> 99             gui, backend = self.shell.enable_matplotlib(args.gui.lower() if isinstance(args.gui, str) else args.gui)
    100             self._show_matplotlib_backend(args.gui, backend)
    101 

~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py in enable_matplotlib(self, gui)
   3412                 gui, backend = pt.find_gui_and_backend(self.pylab_gui_select)
   3413 
-> 3414         pt.activate_matplotlib(backend)
   3415         pt.configure_inline_support(self, backend)
   3416 

~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/pylabtools.py in activate_matplotlib(backend)
    312 
    313     import matplotlib.pyplot
--> 314     matplotlib.pyplot.switch_backend(backend)
    315 
    316     # This must be imported last in the matplotlib series, after

~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py in switch_backend(newbackend)
    220                 "Cannot load backend {!r} which requires the {!r} interactive "
    221                 "framework, as {!r} is currently running".format(
--> 222                     newbackend, required_framework, current_framework))
    223 
    224     rcParams['backend'] = rcParamsDefault['backend'] = newbackend

ImportError: Cannot load backend 'Qt5Agg' which requires the 'qt5' interactive framework, as 'headless' is currently running
```

I tried running first:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')
```

but if i run again `%matplotlib qt`, i'm getting the same error.
If i don't run the magic command, and i plot something, it doesn't show anything.

Comment: The error you show is about the tk backend, but in the text you say you set the qt backend. Which one is it? In any case make sure the required GUI toolkit is installed correctly.

Comment: Oh, that was my error, i'll fix it right now. However, i get the same error with any of those backend. How do i check if i have installed the GUI toolkit?

Comment: For tk `import tkinter`. For qt `import PyQt5`.

Comment: I keep getting the same error.

Comment: In which of the cases do you get which error? (It can't be the exact same, because that is triggered by matplotlib, while the above does not even load matplotlib)

Comment: If I run %matplotlib qt, i get the error that you can see above. If i run %matplotlib tk, i get something similar: `ImportError: Cannot load backend 'TkAgg' which requires the 'tk' interactive framework, as 'headless' is currently running`. And that happens even if i run `import tkinter` or `import PyQt5` before.

Comment: Are you running this on a server without display?

Comment: No, it's a common Jupyter notebook.